# Arithmetic Series, when $n$ tends to infinity the limit is $24$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, arithmetic

The $n$-th term of a sequence is $U_n$

$$U_{n+1}=pU_n+q$$

- $p$ and $q$ are constants
- the first two terms are $U_1=96$ and $U_2=72$
- the limit as $n$ tends to infinity is $24$

> a) show that $p=2/3$
>
> b) find the value of $U_3$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! To attract answers to your question, please add some context and background information. For example, where did you encounter this problem (e.g. a book, class, real-life)? Please also show your attempt; seeing your work helps us help you. If this is homework, please read [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/23353).

Comment: Hint: *If the limit exists*, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}U_{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty} U_n$.

Comment: Hint: $U_{1+1}=pU_1+q$

Comment: @darya khosrotash: this is in fact just a sequence with a recurrence

Answer (score 3):

(1): $72=96*p+q$

$lim_{n\to\infty}U_n=lim_{n\to\infty}U_{n+1}$.

(2): $24=24*p+q$

Solving the two inequalities we get,
$p=\frac{2}{3},q=8$

$U_3=\frac{2}{3}*72+8=56$

Comment: Thank you!I managed to create the first simultaneous equation but couldn't figure out what to create the second one from!

Comment: @NiamhTiera The second one comes from taking limits on both sides of the recurrence $\lim U_{n+1}=\lim(pU_n+q)$ and using that $\lim U_{n+1}=\lim U_n=24$.

Comment: I think you mean geometric  Series (not Arithmetic Series ) because Arithmetic Series has only infinity limit , $$u_{1}=96 \\,u_{2}=72 \\ u_{n}=u_{1}*q^{n-1}\\ q=\frac{72}{96}=2/3\\u_{3}=u_{1}*q^{2}=96*(\frac{2}{3})^2=48\\u_{1}+u_{2}+u_{1}+...+u_{n}=\frac{u_{1}*(1-q^{n})}{1-q}\\$$